# How can I check if a html document includes script tags that are not empty using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if a html document includes script tags that are not empty using regular expressions. The regular expression should match any script tag with a content other than whitespaces or linebreaks.

I have tried

```
<script\b[^>]*>[^.+$]</script>
```

but this regex only finds script tags with one space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @John Sheehan that post doesn't apply here

Comment: I am using the Java 4 regular expression engine (java.util.regex)

Comment: @Jan Kuboschek: Yes, yes it does... HTML + Regex = No, no

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Don't parse HTML with regexen!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)  Seriously, it's literally impossible in the general case.  Why do you want to use a regex here?  It would make much more sense to use an HTML parser, though I can't give you any particular suggestions because I don't know what language you're using.  If you're using the JavaScript DOM, for instance, you would want something like the following:

```
var scripts     = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
var numScripts  = scripts.length
var textScripts = []
for (var i = 0; i < numScripts; ++i)
  if (scripts[i].text !== '') textScripts.push(scripts[i])
```

This looks at the *structure* of the HTML to determine the properties of the script tags, rather than at the messy text.

---

**Edit 1:** Apparently, you're using Java.  Unfortunately, I don't know anything about parsing HTML in Java, so I can't give you any recommendations; however, look into that, because it's the way to go.

Comment: It's easy to copy-paste text this way. ;) BTW, the OP is using java.util.regex, according to his/her comment.

Answer (score 4):

Regex is not the right tool for this. Use a [HTML parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers). I can recommend [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993515");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

Elements scripts = document.select("script");
for (Element script : scripts) {
    String data = script.data();
    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Jsoup is the least verbose of all HTML parsers, it offers a nice API with support for [jQuery like selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

Although you *can* match script tags containing *only* whitespaces or linebreaks, you *cannot* match script tags containing *not only* whitespaces or linebreaks, because the content of the tag may contain script tags itself, and any regex you may come up would match the closing tag sometimes too early or sometimes too late.

You would need to recognise a variant of the *language of properly nested brackets*, which is impossible with regular expressions, because the language is not a regular language.

The problem is further complicated by the possibility of comments containing script tags.

Answer (score 1):

[You should not use a regular expression to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Use [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or another [Java DOM parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) to find this out.

**Under no circumstance use regular expressions to parse HTML.**